# Lyx text does not start at the same place in a long sentence

Tags: lyx

[image: LYX Text]

[image: PDF]

I want that my text starts everytime in the same place :(  How could I fix this?

Comment: If you go to Document > Settings > Text Layout and put the bullet point on "Indentation" and then change "Default" to "Custom" and then put 0 in the box and then press OK, does that do what you want?

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO BROTHER! THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad we got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document > Settings > Text Layout and put the bullet point on "Indentation" and then change "Default" to "Custom" and then put 0 in the box and then press OK.